# BinarySearch Tree implementation & traversals

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search

I am practicing various tree algorithms and that require code review for it's efficiency, clarity and also if it can be made better etc.

Is there a better way to call `parent.findMin(parent)`

**TreeNode.java**

```
package binarytree;

public class TreeNode 
{
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    int data;
    TreeNode parent;
    int size=0;

    TreeNode(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        size = 1;
    }

    int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    void setLeftChild(TreeNode left)
    {
        this.left = left;
        if(left == null)
        {
            left.parent = this;
        }
    }

    void setRightChild(TreeNode right)
    {
        this.right = right;
        if(right == null)
        {
            right.parent =  this;
        }
    }

    void insertInOrder(int d)
    {
        if(d <= data)
        {
            if(left == null)
            {
                setLeftChild(new TreeNode(d));
            }
            else
            {
                left.insertInOrder(d);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(right == null)
            {
                setRightChild(new TreeNode(d));
            }
            else{
                right.insertInOrder(d);
            }
        }
        size++;
    }

    void postOrderTraversal(TreeNode parent)
    {
        if(parent == null) return;

        postOrderTraversal(parent.left);
        postOrderTraversal(parent.right);
        printVal(parent);
    }

    void preOrderTraversal(TreeNode parent)
    {
        if(parent == null) return;

        printVal(parent);
        preOrderTraversal(parent.left);
        preOrderTraversal(parent.right);
    }

    void inOrderTraversal(TreeNode parent)
    {
        if(parent == null) return;

        inOrderTraversal(parent.left);
        printVal(parent);
        inOrderTraversal(parent.right);
    }

    void printVal(TreeNode parent)
    {
        System.out.print(parent.data + "\t");
    }

    /* binary tree find Minimum */
    int findMin(TreeNode parent)
    {
        if(parent == null) return 0;

        int min = parent.data;
        if(parent.left !=null)
        {
            min = Math.min(min, findMin(parent.left));
        }

        if(parent.right != null)
        {
            min = Math.min(min, findMin(parent.right));
        }

        return min;
    }

     /* binary tree find Maximum */
    int findMax(TreeNode parent)
    {
        if(parent == null) return 0;

        int max = parent.data;
        if(parent.left !=null)
        {
            max = Math.max(max, findMax(parent.left));
        }
        if(parent.right != null)
        {
            max = Math.max(max, findMax(parent.right));
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

**Traversal.java**

```
package binarytree;

import binarytree.TreeNode;
public class Traversals {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TreeNode parent = new TreeNode(1);
        TreeNode left = new TreeNode(2);
        TreeNode right = new TreeNode(3);
        TreeNode next = new TreeNode(5);

        parent.insertInOrder(left.data);
        parent.insertInOrder(right.data);
        parent.insertInOrder(next.data);

        System.out.println("Pre-order traversal");
        parent.preOrderTraversal(parent);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Post-order traversal");
        parent.postOrderTraversal(parent);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("In-order traversal");
        parent.inOrderTraversal(parent);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("min element:"+parent.findMin(parent));
        System.out.println("max element:"+parent.findMax(parent));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few things you can do to improve this:

- You don't specify visibility of your methods or variables.  Presumably you want your variables to be `private`, but I'm not sure which of your methods you want `public` or not. I imagine you don't want `setLeftChild` or `setRightChild` to be public since you can't enforce your ordering constraints if anyone can just change children when they feel like it.
- Both `setLeftChild` and `setRightChild` will throw `NullPointerException`s when passed a null value. You want `!=` instead of `==` in your check.
- Do your nodes need references to their parents?
- In your `Traversals` class you have nodes named `parent`, but you are actually referring to the root node of your tree. I would rename that.
- You don't need to create the other three `TreeNode` classes since you only use them to get the value that you passed into them when you call `insertInOrder`.  Just call `insertInOrder` with the values you want.
- You shouldn't pass in the `parent` parameter to your traversal methods. These are instance methods and can just refer to the member variables directly.
- Initialize `size` once.  Currently you set it to 0 and then 1.
- I'm assuming you have plans to use `size` later on. Otherwise you can just remove it entirely.

Comment: You don't need to create the other three TreeNode... how would I do it otherwise?

Comment: `parent.insertInOrder(2)`, `parent.insertInOrder(3)`, `parent.insertInOrder(5)`.

Answer (score 2):

Rethink `findMax`. The way you constructed the tree, a maximal value is never in the left subtree. Similarly, if there is a right subtree, the maximal value is always there.

Comment: true but can u give a example?

Comment: can u suggest a better way to call parent.findMin(parent)

Comment: `findMax`: follow right branch as long as possible. Return the leaf value. `findMin`: same, but follow left branch. Neither needs to be recursive.